# what is an easy way to access documentation for ruby-based gems locally?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rdoc

I have a bunch of gems that I use, but am often disconnected and want to be able to pull up documentation on the gems locally.

so far, the only thing I've been able to do is actually go to the gem library and find the README.

Is there a better way that shows the readme and the full documentation locally without going to the web/github?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `gem server`? I don't install RDocs, but I believe it will provide a way to browse the RDocs while offline.

Comment: I tried, for example, acts_as_commentable_with_threading and it only has a www version....

Comment: I don't know that plugin, but does it use RDoc? I think it has to use RDoc for you to see documentation on the plugin. Someone can downvote me if I'm wrong :P

Answer (score 0):

```
gem server
```

And some more characters.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on the "some more characters"?

Comment: @theIV He means that just typing "gem server" is not enough characters to make a legal answer for Stack Overflow, so he had to type a few more characters so that he could post.

Comment: @Phrogz ah. Makes sense now :P

Answer (score 0):

```
gem server
```

This will launch a [local web server](http://localhost:8808/) that you can browse. If the gem includes documentation, you get it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following simple shell script that allows me to browse everything offline and at my prompt:

```
> cat ~/bin/rim
ri -Tf ansi -w 150 $1
```

usage

```
> rim Bundler

Bundler

(from gem bundler-1.0.10)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Constants:

[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are alot of other tools here if you don't like

```
gem server
```

http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/gem_doc_viewers.html

Answer (score 0):

Ref. http://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-basics/#viewing-documentation

You can use `ri [options] [names]` command, e.g. `ri RBTree`. `ri --help` for more info.

or `gem server` command, where you can access the docs at localhost:8808